# Update Firestore document from cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to update the field *score* from a particular document in collection *users*:

Can find this documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web) for all languages except the only one that works with Firebase CLI

This is what I'm trying based on those examples:

```
exports.updateScore = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
    admin.firestore().collection("users").document("asdfoij32").update("score", 44);
    return res.send('That's done')
});
```

It's throwing this error:

```
TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).document is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodejs JavaScript API uses [doc()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#doc) instead of document() to build a DocumentReference from a CollectionReference.

Comment: That did it! Thanks Doug